# Drawing an axis aligned bounding box around objects

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I want to draw an axis aligned bounding box(AABB) around some point clouds. I wrote its related code in c++ and can see my point clouds with:

```
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("Simple Cloud Viewer");
viewer.showCloud (cloud);
```

I have computed the coordinates of each object's AABB, now I was wondering whether there is a way that I can show AABB cube around my point clouds on the current cloud viewer, means I can have point clouds and their AABB in the result image?
meanwhile, I know in "http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/moment_of_inertia.php#moment-of-inertia" there is a solution for my problem. But my pcl is older than running this code,( it needs pcl 1.8 and my pcl is 1.2) That's why I wrote AABB code by myself. Now, only I want to show my AABB cubes. Is there any way?
I appropriate your kindly helps :)

Comment: Why don't you simply update to 1.8? :)

Comment: I use addline instruction. but always I recieve this error: "invalid use of qualified-name ‘pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addLine’ ", whether pcl 1.2 does not support addline ???